# Is between the correct word when there are more than two items, for example 'a balance between a, b, and c'?

Tags: word-usage

I know we can say, for example, "*a balance between a and b*".
Is it valid to say "*a balance between a, b and c*"?

Because I'm not sure whether "*between*" can be used for more than two items.
If not, what should be a proper word to use?

Comment: Related question on English Language and Usage. [“between” vs. “among”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37636/between-vs-among). It all depends on context and it is wrong to believe "between" can't be used for more than 2 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, it's sooner a matter of collocations (set phrases/word combinations) with the word "balance" as in "the balance *of* animals and plants in the environment, the balance *of* advantage/forces/power".

There's no usage of the preposition "among" after the noun "balance", if that is what you mean. So, "*the* balance between a, b and c" is correct.

To see the difference between "between" and "among", you've already gotten the link, which is in the comment to your question.

Comment: thanks, its more like "find a balance ___ health, work and family", should i use "of" or "between"?

Comment: You should use "between" as you are trying to find the balance between three things.

Comment: My answer is about the choice between "between" and "among"  after the noun "balance" had you had that in mind when you formulated the question. And once again, in the comment above, there's a link that might help with those.

Comment: sure, that helps a lot