# "choosing one method from a, b, or c" OR "choosing one method from a, b, and c" OR "choosing among a, b, or c"

Tags: grammar

What would be best to write?

1. choosing one method from a, b, or c
2. choosing one method from a, b, and c
3. choosing among a, b, or c

Or is there a better option?

Comment: Also *choosing **between** a, b, and/or c*, and doubtless others (*choice **of** a, b, or c*, for example). There is no unambiguously "best" preposition. Nor would most native speakers care one way or the other whether you used ***and*** or ***or*** for your final conjunction in this exact context (since inclusive ***and*** matches the context of *what you get to choose from*, but exclusive ***or*** matches *the one you actually choose*). Except *choice of a, b, and c* might often imply you actually chose ***all of them***).

Comment: Is 'between' correct when we have more than two options?

Comment: That's been [asked before on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/88405/) - though not well answered there, I'm afraid. But it was [also asked on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37636/) years before ELL even existed. And the overwhelmingly top-rated answer there kicks off in no uncertain terms by saying that "rule" is [***Prescriptivist Poppycock ... A Rule That Doesn’t Rule ... OED: In all senses, between has been, from its earliest appearance, extended to more than two.***](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/193840/2637)

Comment: @FumbleFingers -- Your comment(s) would make a good answer.

Comment: @Jasper: I'm older (but not necessarily *wiser* :) than when I wrote those comments. I can't remember if I might have closevoted at the time, but looking at it again now I don't know what I was thinking when I wrote the *second* comment. It seems to be focused on the possibility of using ***between***  with more than 2 choices - but although that's mentioned in my *first* comment, the OP never asked about that. Anyway, I see now that I can't endorse the only answer here (because it says *assuming the choice is **mutually exclusive** to a, b, and c*), so I'll act on your suggestion.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Your second comment was in response to the original poster's follow-up question (in a comment).

Answer (score 1):

> 1: *Choose one method from a, b, or c*
> 2: *Choose one method from a, b, and c*
> 3: *Choose among a, b, or c*

Option #3 is idiomatically unlikely, but it would be fine with a different preposition - for example, ***from*** or ***between*** - rather than ***among***.

I don't think it makes any difference whether you use ***and*** or ***or*** as the "list separator", but it's perhaps worth noting that syntactically / logically, whichever "coordinating conjunction" you *explicitly* use before the last item in the list is also *implicitly* present before all other listed possibilities after the first one.

There is no unambiguously "best" preposition OR conjunction here. Nor would most native speakers care one way or the other whether you used ***and*** or ***or*** for your final conjunction in this exact context (since "inclusive" ***and*** matches the context of what you get to choose *from*, but "exclusive" ***or*** matches the one you *actually* choose).

Note that example #3, where it's not explicitly stated that you may only choose *one*, is inherently ambiguous regardless of which preposition and conjunction you use. Syntactically speaking, you don't know if you're allowed to choose more than one possibility unless you ask for clarification.

Answer (score -1):

Your example answers itself, if you are only choosing *one*, it would be

> **choose from a,b, or c**
>   **choose from a,b, and c**

both are correct assuming the choice is mutually exclusive to a, b, and c.

If you changed your example around a bit

> Choose your meal from our appetizers, mains, **and** desserts.

one would use ***"and"*** since something is chosen from *each of the categories*.

> Choose your vacation destination from the Americas, Europe, **or** the Far East.

Would be similar to your example, however

> > Choose your vacation destination from the Americas, Europe, **and**  the Far East.

does get used and is understandable.